# How to print a MAX and a description from Java Database

Tags: java, sql

I'm beginning to learn about connecting to databases via Java programs. I have a table called City, which contains just two columns: CityName and Population. I want to find the highest population, and then give that population along with the name of the corresponding city.

I know how to get just the highest population (see the following, which I know is probably not ideal but at least is working for me):

```
            double max = 0.0;
            String sqlStatement = "SELECT MAX(Population) FROM City"; 
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
            if (result.next())
            {
                   highest = result.getDouble(1);
            }
            System.out.printf("Highest population: %,.0f", highest);
```

I am pretty sure that to get the highest population PLUS the name of the corresponding city, my Sql statement should eb changed to :

`"SELECT CityName, MAX(Population) FROM City GROUP BY CityName";`

But I can't get it to work beyond that. I thought I could add something like

`String highestCity = result.getString(2)`

and then add highestCity to the System.out.printf output line, but that isn't working.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the city that have the greatest population?

Comment: I want to give the greatest population (the actual number), and the name of the city that has the greatest population. Thanks for all the replies, will test some and reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this ?

```
 String sqlStatement = "SELECT CityName, Population FROM City WHERE Population IN (SELECT MAX(Population) FROM City)";
```

Comment: Sorry, you are completely correct! My mistake. I took an erroneus result of my DBMS as something correct. I already voted to delete my answer since it is incorrect.

Comment: Would be better if you used `=`, vs `IN`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to sort your results by population descending, and limit your query to only return one result.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this don't cover if more than one city have value = max population